# D3.js and InnerHtml not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a dashboard that uses D3.js graphs as well as some inner HTML calls to display some metrics. One of my co-workers and I can see the graphs and numbers that are calculated on our different machines from IE. However, another 2 can't, nothing shows up but the wells and panels that hold them. The site is built in MVC .net 4.5.

I checked to see if they had scripting enabled, which they did? So what else could it be?

Also, I just checked. They are using IE 8 and we are using IE 11(the intranet site is only set up for IE).

Comment: Different versions of IE? Or other browser? Or firewall settings? You're not really giving us anything to go on here.

Comment: I just checked their IE, and that is a factor. I am using IE 11 as well as my other co-worker. They are both using IE 8

Comment: I'm guessing that your dashboard uses SVG, which isn't supported in IE8.

Comment: Yes it is, good to know. That explains the D3 problem...